# Is there a vertical bar as long as the integral sign?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, displaystyle, vertical, integral

I'm looking for a big **vertical bar** that puts the lower and upper elements at the same height as on the default integral sign.  Currently, using `\Big|` (or `\Bigr|`), and `\bigg|` (or `\biggr|`) gives an ugly output.  Here's a MWE to show my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \int_{-\, a}^{+\, a} f(x) \frac{d}{dx} \: \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \, dx \\[2ex]
\begin{aligned}
    &= f(x) \, \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \biggr|_{-\, a}^{+\, a} - \int_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a \frac{d}{dx} \: f(x) \, dx \\[2ex]
    &= f(x) \, \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \Bigr|_{-\, a}^{+\, a} - \int_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a \frac{d}{dx} \: f(x) \, dx \\[2ex]
    &= f(a) - f(x) \biggr|_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a = f(a) - f(x) \Big|_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong with this code?  How could I draw a vertical bar that puts its two elements exactly at the same position as an integral sign?

(note that I'm using the tensor package for another reason, not relevant here)

---

**EDIT:**. I could define a custom vertical bar of the same size as the integral sign using the scalerel package:

```
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\eval}{\stretchrel*{|}{\int}}
```

but then the lower and upper elements aren't placed at the proper position.  So no luck here.

Comment: Why not use a `\left.`...`\right|` pair?

Comment: @Werner, it doesn't work.  The size isn't right.  And it's more complicated to type because of the left part.

Answer (score 8):

Define `\def\myvert{\biggr|{\vphantom{\int}}}` and use `\myvert_{..}^{..}` instead `\biggr|_{..}^{..}`.

**Edit:** If you want to have equal size of the bar and the `\int` then you can define it as `\vrule`:

```
\def\myvert{{\mkern2mu\vrule\,\vphantom{\int}}}
```

Comment: I could combine your solution with my stretched bar defined in my edit above.

Comment: @Cham OK, you are asking for simpler way. So I added another solution using `\vrule` primitive, you don't need load any next LaTeX package.

Comment: `\def\myvert{\mathclose{...}}`?

Comment: Yes, it should be better because Inner (a `\left...\right` construction) should preceded. And Inner-Close is without space, Inner-Ord with small space. The right side of `\myvert` are unchanged, because Ord-* is equal to Close-*. The other differences Bin-Close, Rel-Close, Op-Close are unlikely in this situation.

Comment: Well, the **scalerel** package was already loaded just for another macro I'm using, so no problem here.  But your new definition is a nice one too.

Comment: I love this page just because after years (going on decades) of using (la)tex it keeps teaching me new things like `\vphantom`. I was living on unwieldy constructs along the lines of `\sbox0`,  `\ht0` and `\dp0` ...

Answer (score 4):

Combining wipet's answer and a scaled up version of |, I get good results:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\eval}{\stretchrel*{|}{\int}{\vphantom{\int}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \int_{-\, a}^{+\, a} f(x) \frac{d}{dx} \: \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \, dx \\[2ex]
\begin{aligned}
    &= f(x) \, \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \biggr|_{-\, a}^{+\, a} - \int_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a \frac{d}{dx} \: f(x) \, dx \\[2ex]
    &= f(x) \, \Theta(x - \tensor{x}{_0}) \eval_{-\, a}^{+\, a} - \int_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a \frac{d}{dx} \: f(x) \, dx \\[2ex]
    &= f(a) - f(x) \eval_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a = f(a) - f(x) \Big|_{\tensor{x}{_0}}^a.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a simpler or better way of getting the same result.